# Javascript: Looping through an array to create listeners, issue with call by reference and value?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
for (var i=0; i<layerCount; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<layerData[i].data.length; j++){
        var text = layerData[i].data[j].text;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(layerData[i].data[j].lat, layerData[i].data[j].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latlng});
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: text});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map,marker);});
    }
}
```

The problem in the above code most likely is in the line starting with `google.maps.event.addListener`. Whichever marker I click, I get a infowindow opening up for the last item in the data field of `layerdata[i].data[j]`. Seems like I am calling by reference and not by value, so `infowindow` and `marker` for all listeners are the last items in the arrays.

But how can I solve this?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/):

```
for (var i=0; i<layerCount; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<layerData[i].data.length; j++){
        var text = layerData[i].data[j].text;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(layerData[i].data[j].lat, layerData[i].data[j].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latlng});
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: text});

        bindOpenWindow(infowindow, map, marker);
    }
}

function bindOpenWindow(infowindow, map, marker)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map, marker);});
}
```

See if it helps ;)

Comment: +1 Reusable named functions are so much better and clearer than building an IIFE in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no concept of block scope, only function and global scope. You can use a closure to work around it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < layerCount; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < layerData[i].data.length; j++){
        var text = layerData[i].data[j].text;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(layerData[i].data[j].lat, layerData[i].data[j].lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latlng});
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: text});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(infowindow, marker) {
            return function() {infowindow.open(map, marker);};
        })(infowindow, marker));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem for `infowindow`, but not the `marker` variable.