# How to iterate data to create markers for Google Maps (using express/jquery/ajax) currently getting SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, express

I initialize a google map here: (which is working fine, but I'll include for background)

this entire code comes inside of a .ejs file

```
    <head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var loadMap = function() {
        var myOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.952335, -75.163789),
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadMap()">
```

then when I try to iterate over my date to add my markers -  I get an error (code works without this segment in it)

This is what I have so far:
Also note that because of express (I think it's express at least) I can use the <% code code code %> to write javascript inside of an html file.

```
<!-- data is an array of arrays [name, lat, lon, description, creator] -->

<% for (var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) { 
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        info.setContent( %><b><% "Name: "+array[0][i] %></b><% +". Description: "+array[3][i] %><i><% +". Creator: "+array[4][i] %></i><% );

        var newCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(array[1][i], array[2][i]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newCoords,
            map: map,
            title: array[0][i],
            if (message == array[0][i]) { // if the creator is currently signed in (his additions should be yellow on map)
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
            }
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(info, marker) {
            return function() { 
                info.open(map, marker);};
            })(info, marker))
}; %>
```

I'm getting a Unexpected Token : ';'
In case there's any confusion there I'm trying to add new markers for the data in my array, have it be clickable and display text in there that's partly bolded, partly italicized.

also, im using closure at the end there to make sure each event listener is unique (copied from here: [Javascript: Looping through an array to create listeners, issue with call by reference and value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006447/javascript-looping-through-an-array-to-create-listeners-issue-with-call-by-ref))

Hope eyes more experienced than I can spot my error or suggest a better alternative... I've tried taking out every single non-essential semi-colon but it accomplished nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, marker should be:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newCoords,
        map: map,
        title: array[0][i],
        icon : (message == array[0][i])? //use ternary
          'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
          : undefined 
    });
```

You can't have if statements in an object literal but you can assign icon with a ternary expression. If it's a problem that icon is undefined you can do it outside the object literal:

```
    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    markerDetails;
    //...code
    markerDetails = {
        position: newCoords,
        map: map,
        title: array[0][i]
    };
    if (message == array[0][i]) { 
      markerDetails.icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
    }
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerDetails);
```

Comment: @gadu ternary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator Maybe you got it working already but if setting icon to undefined you could set it outside the body of the object literal and use an if statement as in the added code to the answer.